# Android experimental gradle source

Tags: android, gradle

Anyone know the new way to set a manifest source location in the experimental plugin?

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.1.0"
}
```

I believe I have java and resources correct, but can't figure out manifest:

```
android.sources {
    main {
        //manifest.source.srcDir 'library'
        manifest.srcFile = file('library/AndroidManifest.xml')
        //manifest.srcFile 'library'
        resources.source.srcDir 'library/res'
        java.source.srcDir 'library/src'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

```
android.sources {
    main {
        manifest.source {
            srcDir 'library'
            include 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        resources.source.srcDir 'library/res'
        java.source.srcDir 'library/src'
    }
}
```

*Note that since the plugin is experimental this is likely to change version-to-version.*

Comment: I gave up on the experimental plugin for the moment due to missing support for a lot of the prior functionality.  I'll test this in the coming month or so as it matures.  How did you figure this out?

Comment: It seemed to me that the manifest sourceSet was likely treated specially by the Android Gradle plugin - we seem to have lost that functionality in the experimental version so this is just a generic Gradle sourceSet with the single manifest file included.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4`. The way I solve it was with the following code:

```
    sources {
        main {
            manifest {
                source {
                    srcDirs = [ "library" ]
                }
            }
            res {
                source {
                    srcDirs = [ "library/res" ]
                }
            }
            java {
                source {
                    srcDirs = [ "library/src" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```